# Anyone knows where Shazam stores tags?

Tags: shazam

I have an android and all of a sudden shazam doesn't work.  It crashes whenever I open it up, so I want to clear the data but I have a lot of tags in there and I want to download the songs but I can't even look through the list...  Anyone know where the tags are stored and if there is a way for me to retrieve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it seems the only way to do this on android is to contact shazam customer support, give them your IMEI number and they will send you the list.